# macOS toolbar items with image and text in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, toolbar

I'd like to achieve something similar in SwiftUI to what is described in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines about [toolbars](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/toolbars/).

[image]

I tried using `.toolbar { }` but items are too small and NavigationLink doesn't change the selected View. I tried setting `ExpandedWindowToolbarStyle()` on WindowGroup.

Code:

```swift
NavigationView { }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.automatic) {
                HStack {
                    Text("")
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: getDestination(forOption: Option.home)) {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: Option.home.iconName)

                            Text("test")
                        }
                        .frame(height: 50)


                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

current state:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a customizable toolbar and labels.

[image]

```
        .toolbar(id: "Main") {
            ToolbarItem(id: "Sidebar") {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Label("Sidebar", systemImage: "sidebar.right")
                }
            }
        }
```

Also it might be possible to use TitleAndIconLabelStyle with MacOS 11.3. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't provide a solution for embedding the navigation links in toolbar items. I tried a few different solution but with no success

Comment: @mikro098 A `NavigationLink` is just not meant to be within a toolbar. It’s meant for `NavigationView`.

Comment: Super helpful @Stephan Michels! Please notice that giving the toolbar an `id` is necessary for it to be configurable by the user.